# WordPress : How to remove unecessary breakline<br> tags in <p> and <ul><li> tags

Tags: wordpress

Hi I have this wordpress site, and I want to remove the unnecessary breakline tag that automatically inserts into the `<ul><li> tag` this is the code that I insert it in functions.php file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );

add_filter( 'the_content', 'nl2br' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'nl2br' );

add_filter('the_content', 'remove_empty_p', 20, 1);
function remove_empty_p($content){
    $content = force_balance_tags($content);
    return preg_replace('#<p>\s*+(<br\s*/*>)?\s*</p>#i', '', $content);
}
```

The nl2br will breakline the_content on it. But it seems that `<ul><li>`
also inserts a breakline to it.

I want that only `<p>` tag will breakline.

My problem is how will I be able to prevent that it wont add a breakline inside `<ul><li>` tag?

Can anyone help me on this?

Any help is much appreciated. TIA

Comment: Hello you can try to do it by CSS ( ul li br {display:none} ) or you can make it by giving Class to that particular Ul...

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');    
function remove_empty_p( $content ) {
    $content = force_balance_tags( $content );
    $content = preg_replace( '#<p>\s*+(<br\s*/*>)?\s*</p>#i', '', $content );
    $content = preg_replace( '~\s?<p>(\s|&nbsp;)+</p>\s?~', '', $content );
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_empty_p', 20, 1); 

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: It removes extra empty `<p>` or `<br>` tags added by wordpress editor automatically

Comment: @phpdev : yes. It will remove all empty and unnecessary p tag and breaklines